# Any reason not to remove all default WP plugins?

Tags: plugins

I'm new to WP and set up an app on cloudways. It came with some plugins by default like `bot protection` or `breeze`. I've seen a tutorial video where the guide just removed all plugins, the first thing he did, before installing elementor.

I do not plan using a page builder for this particular project and wanted to know, if I can just dump all plugins like he did or if I should leave them?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Site Health screen

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/db30405f478e9813b0cc59f81992f16eb0a29ced/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php#L470

```
Inactive plugins are tempting targets for attackers. 
If you're not going to use a plugin, you should consider removing it.
```

Default plugins are Hello Dolly and Akismet.

Your hosting provider is most likely adding the other plugins you mentioned as  pre-installed plugins for their customers as an extra value.

So consider removing them if you don't plan to use them but contact your hosting provider on how you can get them (i.e. the paid ones) back if you later change your mind.